# Modifying controls collection error in VB.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, controls

I need a function to be performed on the page load, which uses a stored session variable. I have added the following to my `<body>` tag.

```
<body onload="doSomething(event,'<%= Session("StartTime") %>')>
```

This does work. However, it is causing a problem elsewhere, when I try to add a control to my controls collection:

```
dim myPanel= New Panel
...
Me.Controls.Add(myPanel)
```

It bombs out at this stage, giving the following error:

> "The Controls collection cannot be
>   modified because the control contains
>   code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). "

I've tried the suggestion of using `<%#`...`%>` instead of `<%=`..`.%>`, but this prevents the session variable being found- it is just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or,

```
<body onload="doSomething(event,'<asp:PlaceHolder id="starttimePlaceholder" runat="server"</asp:Placeholder>')>
```

Then, on the server side to populate it:

```
starttimePlaceholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(Session("StartTime")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [a solution that worked](http://blog.js-development.com/2008/08/controls-collection-cannot-be-modified.html)

I forced my script to run on a server-control.

```
<body ms_positioning="GridLayout" onload="callFromDiv(event);">

         <div runat="server" ID="serverDiv">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  //This function must be placed in a separate div, since placing it directly 
                  //in body tag prevents new controls being added later
                  function callFromDiv(e){
                      doSomething(e,'<%= Session("StartTime") %>')
                  }  
            </script>
        </div>
```